# What's the status of the HTML 5 <video> tag and webcam integration?

Tags: video, html, webcam

Even though it seems to be in some kind of jeopardy, the open video standard is a great idea. I saw some demos on motion tracking with it - just proofs-of-concept, but interesting nonetheless. Now, I'd say that concepts like these would *really* be a gain, if there would be access to the user's webcam... Just imagine browsing through Flickr with your hands in mid-air.

I have Googled a little, but I can't find any detailed discussion on the subject. It is mentioned in some places, but that doesn't get me very far. Does anybody know whether support for this is planned? If yes, any prognosis on the 'when'? ;-)

Of course, I guess they'd have to dream up a pretty good security model for it..

Comment: Ericsson has some interesting ideas around this: https://labs.ericsson.com/developer-community/blog/beyond-html5-conversational-voice-and-video-implemented-webkit-gtk

Comment: 3 years later here's the current status, some support in Chrome and Opera: http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/06/html5/filtering-a-webcam-using-getusermedia-and-html5-canvas

Comment: is there a way to output the /dev/tty from java and then decode the image in a Java / JavaScript decoder?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, still no clear, definitive answers, so I went on and took a little action. The WHATWG would probably have an answer for me, so I decided to contact someone there. Didn't really know who it had to be, but fellow Dutchman [Anne van Kesteren](http://annevankesteren.nl) usually seems to know the Web's future pretty well - plus, he provides an e-mail address.

Translating his response probably won't do any good, so in short: there are some rough ideas on how to make it all work, but there's nothing tangible at the moment. The [Device APIs and Policy Working Group](http://www.w3.org/2009/05/DeviceAPICharter) is supposed to continue work on this.

Reading through their page makes me realize something else too - why only *webcam* access? If Google intends to move the OS to the browser, we'll need more than just webcams. Why not manage your iPod through a webapp too? Anything should be possible. I guess a whole new concept of 'trusted website' will have to evolve *if* functionality like this would come available, but well, there's a solution to pretty much *anything*, isn't there? ;-)

Comment: Here’s a blog post about an HTML `<devices>` element added to the spec during discussions on the possible API: http://blog.whatwg.org/whats-next-in-html-episode-1

Comment: Oh, and re Google and their plans, I think you’ll be able to plug your digital cameras and whatnot into Chrome OS. Whether that makes it into an implemented web standard is another matter.

Comment: While I like your answer, your last sentence is fodder for conversation.  "a whole new concept of 'trusted website'" will be invented by Verisign. It will cost a s***ton. It won't be pretty. And, much like a "properly" signed SSL cert, it will be a gimmick, doing essentially nothing more than providing the end user with the comfort of some eye candy that they don't understand.

Comment: lol manage your ipod on browser.  like apple would ever allow that.  iphones dont even have filesystems

Answer (score 5):

Updated!: HTMl5Rocks has a very good working demo of this now. Check it out [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)!

Here is a very interesting article with a demo, however the source has not been released yet:
(Read the comments for more information on codecs used, socket server tech, etc)

https://labs.ericsson.com/developer-community/blog/beyond-html5-conversational-voice-and-video-implemented-webkit-gtk

Answer (score 3):

We're working on a project like this..

About the Ericsson's demo that people mentioned; It only works with a patched webkit which isn't released (yet).

We haven't seen any other working projects so this is how we plan to do this:

- Implement the **HTML Media Capture** draft (available [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/capture-api/)) in order to access the raw data.
- Using websockets for sending local data and receiving remote data at the same time.
- Clients "register" on the websocket server with a **callerID**.
- Server has an "invite" API where caller1 "invites" caller2.
- The browser will play this using the HTML5 audio- and HTML5 video tag.

Answer (score 2):

html5 is with us for good, the flash vs silverlight vs html5 question has been around for a while now, but it seems that the trends are pointing towards a merger between our desktop world and our online world. If you've taken a sneak peak at Mac's Lion OS, it is basically app centric, which rides that line between OS level and Online.

The Device API has been drafted and will come to all major browsers with time (WebKit is always the early adopter), but as we all know the w3c takes longer to officially approve additions to the HTML5 specification. Erikson Labs has released their camera/sound capture API (https://labs.ericsson.com/developer-community/blog/beyond-html5-audio-capture-web-browsers) so you can get started today with HTML5 and peripheral support.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this [WebRTC project](http://www.webrtc.org) which is an open source project and gives us the chance to access webcam, microphone without installing any plugings. which i guess Google uses for their developments. so worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

You can now access video / audio hardware directly from the browser (hooray HTML5) but there is no good way to record the stream. To accomplish this you still need to utilize a Flash Media Server (or clone). There are a few good services out there that make this turn-key instead of a giant headache:

http://cameratag.com

http://framebase.io

http://framey.com

Answer (score -8):

It will never be possible because it is the last use of plugins which open web standards cannot accomplish. The day streaming audio/video from client to server will be the end of flash/silverlight/what have you. Also there is software patents issue which will make it impossible to encode media if current state of affairs on decoding means anything.
There are just too many obstacles before privacy or technical issues. Flash has been doing it for years without anybody whinning about any privacy problems. Geolocation is potentially more dangerous but nobody thinks twice considering its rich possibilities. The closest thing you can get is a webcam with MJPEG stream that is wrapped in multipart-replace and using canvas API to get the image pixels.

Comment: Haha - *that's* the spirit!  "No!  We can't do it! Ahhhhh!"

Comment: Yeah, as if wishful thinking will get you anywhere. Go convince apple, microsoft, adobe, opera, mozilla. I do this stuff for a living now and html just doesn't work right now. Try writing code, setting up a blog and crying out your lungs. It will never get you anywhere unless big money decide it is profitable.

Comment: "If you aren’t getting rejected on a daily basis, your goals aren’t ambitious enough." - Chris Dixon

Comment: Congratulations, you have made a politically charged comment on a politically charged answer which is more than a year old. Of course I wish <device> is implemented within, I don't know, maybe 4 years but we are still not there.

Comment: Hello from 2021. Yes, we can do that now and in one line actually.