# Non-flash / No-plugin Video chat?

Tags: ajax, chat

We are developing a social website and looking to implement video/audio chat for users (people a user is friends with). Most of the talk from the tech team was to use flash. But I don't want users to install anything. Can video/audio/conferencing be done purely in AJAX? Either develop it from scratch or use open source frameworks if any?

Answer (score 4):

Flash is already installed on practically ever browser out there -- except iPhones, iPads, etc. which will likely never support Flash.

AJAX and HTML and CSS currently have no access to video and audio input hardware, so that's a non-starter.  In the future this may change.

For now Flash is (for better or for worse) the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately you can only do this with a plugin (ie Flash).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you have access to video or audio input devices from just the browser.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML5** will be the answer in the near future (Work in progress): [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318834/whats-the-status-of-the-html-5-video-tag-and-webcam-integration) and [Link2](http://devworks.thinkdigit.com/Internet/Native-webcam-support-to-come-with-HTML5_3834.html)

But for now the only option is Flash

Comment: I don't know about you, but my definition of "near" future doesn't even come *close* to the time frame in which HTML5-based video conferencing will be possible...

Comment: I agree my friend, "near" is not so near. But looking forward to it!

Comment: Atleast, that's what Apple is also waiting for. So, you never know!