# Open source video chat server not using flash

Tags: flash, real-time, red5, videochat

Reading ["Building the realtime user experience" by Ted Roden](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596806163), I was wondering how to go further and get some **video chat web app** up and running **without the use of flash**.

So, in terms of feasibility:

- client-side: how can one access to cam and mic local streams not using flash ?
- server-side: are there any existing frameworks or open source servers (something like red5) that focus on this kind of use cases ? If not, what do I need to build my own (lightweight) visio chat server ?

I'm afraid flash [seems to be the unique way to go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041819/non-flash-no-plugin-video-chat/3041844#3041844) for the moment, that's why I'm asking you folks, if someone could make it more obvious to me.

Comment: I'm seeking a plugin-less solution

Comment: Flash is dead, http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2015/jan/30/flash-youtube-nostalgia

Comment: Plug-Ins Leaving Google Chrome. http://www.snowbound.com/blog/3204/plug-ins-leaving-google-chrome-what-now/

Comment: Get ready for plug-in free browsing. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh968248%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I haven't read the book, therefore maybe I don't see the point in building a non-flash videochat app **today**.

As you already gave a link to another post, where they talk about html5 and stuff, you can also see that today the easiest way is flash. Not only because it is well documented, but because people usually have flash on their machines - at least those who want to use video chat. This makes it easy to involve them in an experience like that. Flash is installed, so you don't need to force them to download any new plugins.

If new standards allow web developers to get free from flash, you will still need to wait for people to download the new browsers which let them enjoy the new standards.

But going back to your question, if you don't want it today, but asking in general:
According to some pages I don't dare to quote here, html5 is what you are looking for. A "pluginless" world.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it makes sense and it is objective. Still I'm curious to know what are the different means of capturing video/audio from a web client.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to keep an eye on [WebRTC](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html). You can read more about it and the `getUserMedia()` API [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/). Presently, it only seems to be fully supported by Chrome, and partially by Firefox and Opera.

Answer (score 1):

Yep - HTML5 CSS3 and perhaps using a combination of flash and another one or two video technologies to allow for differing browsers and platforms. We are currently looking into developing a project just along these lines. The desire to be on iPhone Android Mac Linux and PC in a public chat is advanced and eventually necessary. To understand the use of the three different technologies see the VideoJS open source project.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'm going to check the VideoJS project.

Comment: Hmmm It looks like a video player only, the idea was to display AND capture video with no flash. But thanks anyway