# Allowing website to use webcam

Tags: webcam, profile, photo

I'm a web developer, and know my way around with php, jscript and little flash. However i was wondering how can i allow my user to use their webcam to capture pic for their profile?

Is it possible with HTML5 or i will have to use flash?

Comment: [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318834/whats-the-status-of-the-html-5-video-tag-and-webcam-integration) might help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It have been long since i posted this question. May be its the wrong place to post. But meanwhile i have been researching and have found a very good way to do this!

[Here is the link to the tutorial](http://kevinmusselman.com/blog/2009/02/access-webcam-with-flash/)

[And here is the working sample of the script.](http://www.kevinmusselman.com/examples/webcam/testvid)

All the used source is posted and well documented. A fla file, a php script and all action script code is included!