# Is there a way to capture video from camera in HTML5?

Tags: html, html5-video, html5-audio

I can not use flash because I need this to work in iPhone.

Which browsers are supported?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318834/whats-the-status-of-the-html-5-video-tag-and-webcam-integration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a proposal for client side camera/microphone access ([Capture API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-media-capture-api-20100928/)). It's currently a draft W3C standard, it's certainly possible that iOS devices will support it, probably some time in the future: