# How to access webcam with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, webcam

I google'd quite a while about this topic, without any satisfying result. Actually my basic question is: Is there any possible way to access a webcam with Javascript ?

Maybe with HTML5 ? `<video>` element ?

What are options as developer to access the computers webcam anyway?

Comment: This will be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083617/accessing-webcam-with-javascript ; cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please see this answer:

[Access webcam without Flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644612/controlling-webcam-via-html5/9646193#9646193)

It is possible with beta browsers but if you want to developer something for IE users you need to stick with Flash.

Comment: More specifically, WebRTC MediaStream is experimentally available in Google Chrome 19 and Opera 12, and is on Mozilla's roadmap for Firefox this year.  Nobody knows if it's in the works for Internet Explorer.