# Reading Server-Side Variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, server

I am using embeded flash for displaying the camera video inside an asp.net project for passing the camera inf. I am writing variables from flash to the server using Tamper Data extension I know it is sending ok.

The problem is *reading* it with javascript. How can I? I'm trying to use JSP with the `<%...%>` but I am not able to read it properly.

This is the code I am using:

```
document.getElementById("txtID").value = "<%=varActionServer.Value%>";
```

Where `txtID` is a textbox and `varActionServer.Value` is the value of the Server variable that I want.

Comment: you mean ASP not JSP?

Comment: <%=varActionServer.Value%> will give you the value at the point the page is loaded. Is that what you intend?

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll It is supposed to be JSP (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaou.html); and I intend that when the page is loaded, I should receive the server variables sended by flash, but what I I'm finding is that first the page is loaded, and then the embeded flash is sending the data. It is a synchronization problem. Now I am searching how to insert something like an Event to catch the changing value in the server variables.

Comment: your first line says 'asp.net' project though?

Comment: Yes, that is my tool to access the server-side, but, but, but, the inf. sent by flash is after the post back is made, so I cannot see it with my c# code.
And @ChrisFCarroll your explanation about the gap between sides helped me a lot with my understatement of the problem, I might have started clarifying those basic concepts from first place. The problem is that all what I'm doing is quasi Autodidactism.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the big gap between client-side and server-side. Serverside variables can only tell you what the server knew when it built the page and **before** it sent it to the client. JSP is a serverside technology and it, too, can only know what the server knew before it sent the page.

What you are trying to achieve is client-side; that after the page has gone to the client, the page can still be updated. For this, you must forget JSP.

I assume that you are going via the server because you already have a working solution that gets data from the camera, through flash, to the server. In that case you can read data from the server using ajax. The simplest route is [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Another option might be to throw out the flash solution and use something else. Here' an SO question about that approach:  [Access camera from a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024770/access-camera-from-a-browser)