# how to make the camera work with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, camera, video-streaming, getusermedia

I know this question has been asked plenty of time, but I can't figure out what is wrong in my code. I have look for in google, here, and many other places where I haven't found a solution yet.
My HTML code is:

```
<button id="camera">Show the camera</button>
<video id="video" class="hidden" preload="none" autoplay>
    <source src="video.webM" type="video/webM">
</video>
```

My JavaScript code is:

```
$("#camera").on("click",function(){ 

        var mediaConfig =  { video: true };
        var video = $("#video")[0];

        // Normalize the various vendor prefixed versions of getUserMedia.
        navigator.getMedia = (  navigator.getUserMedia ||
                                    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                                    navigator.mozGetUserMedia || 
                                    navigator.msGetUserMedia );

        // Check that the browser supports getUserMedia.
        // If it doesn't show an alert, otherwise continue.
        if (navigator.getMedia) {
          // Request the camera.
          navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
            // Constraints
            mediaConfig,

            // Success Callback
            function(localMediaStream) {
                // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
                video.removeClass("hidden");
                video.addClass("showVideo");
                console.log("Camera is activated");
                if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
                    video.mozSrcObject = localMediaStream;
                }else {
                    var vendorURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                    video.src = vendorURL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
                }
                // Create an object URL for the video stream and use this 
                // to set the video source.
                //video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
                video.play();
            },

            // Error Callback
            function(err) {
              // Log the error to the console.
              console.log('The following error occurred when trying to use getUserMedia: ' + err);
                video.removeClass("showVideo");
                video.addClass("hidden");
                alert("error");
            }
          );

        } else {
                video.removeClass("showVideo");
                video.addClass("hidden");
          alert('Sorry, your browser does not support getUserMedia');
        }
```

In the mobile, I get that the browser ask me permissions to Access to the camera, but once I accept, nothing happens: No error, no video, no streamming, just nothing.
Also, I forgot to mention, but the web is in a SSL Server, so is no that problem. 
Would anybody illustrate me a bit??. I don't know what else to do :(
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing the new [`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) promise API with the old deprecated [`navigator.getUserMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia) callback API.

There's also a lot of outdated vendor prefix cruft here (e.g. `video.mozSrcObject` is no more).

Just [use](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/srn9db4h/):

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})
  .then(stream => video.srcObject = stream)
  .catch(e => console.error(e));
```

If you're worried about supporting old browsers, use [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter).

Comment: Sorry, but when I use your code, I get a syntax error, but It is weird because in the fiddle example that you posted, it looks work fine. Any idea??

Comment: @galeonweb How would I know? What's the error and line? What browser and platform? Try removing [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) from the fiddle to see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false })
    .then(localMediaStream => {
        console.log(localMediaStream);
        video.src =window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
    }).catch(err =>{
        console.error('oh why errors!!', err);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to use mediaDevices at all. If you are just after a camera to take a photo then `<input type='file' accept='image/*' capture='camera'>` on a mobile device will do it (note, it behaves differently on a desktop device) and will use the highest resolution on that device (as opposed to the resolution of the video camera). See https://methodfish.com/Articles/javascript-camera for discussion and demo.

Answer (score 0):

The setting of the video stream is not correct. In your success callback you need to have

```
video.srcObject = localMediaStream;
```

Comment: But where should i put that línea? Do i have yo remove mine?? Or just add It?, Sorry, my ignorance

Comment: As @jib is mentioning, some of your method calls are outdated. Everything in your success callback after `console.log("Camera is activated");` can be replaced with the line above.