# How to redirect user to a separate page if they deny camera access?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm **very** new to HTML and JS. I have been trying to find a way to redirect a user to a page if they deny camera access but haven't had any luck. Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to check if geolocation has been DECLINED with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092400/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-geolocation-has-been-declined-with-javascript) Instead of 'geolocation', use 'camera'.

Comment: Where's the code you used without luck and what went wrong? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You should be able to use `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then((stream) => {}).catch((e) =>location.href='');` See https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: @JuanMendes Thanks, Perhaps you could read the entire comment. And it's not a different API, since the accepted answer is using the Permissions API, which is the same in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Taking an example access from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45496905/14550434), you could do something like this:

```js
var facingMode = "user"; // Can be 'user' or 'environment' to access back or front camera (NEAT!)
var constraints = {
  audio: false,
  video: {
   facingMode,
  }
};

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then((stream) => {
    // some code
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // User denied the request
    window.location.replace("https://example.com"); // redirect
  });
```