# how to record the video through webcam using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to record the videos through my webcam and want to upload them to the server. I don't want to use any plugin. How can I atleast just record the videos.

Answer (score 5):

There's a project on GitHub called [**RecordRTC**](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC). It also provides a live demo [**here**](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/). This tool could run on browsers supporting **WebRTC** and **getUserMedia**. It could record both audio and video.

However, according to data from **Can I Use**, currently [**WebRTC**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=rtcpeerconnection) and [**getUserMedia**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream) are only supported by Firefox, Chrome, and other blink engine browsers.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [navigator.getUserMedia](http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream) function.

Check out these url`s. 
[Capturing Audio & Video](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)

Comment: The html5rocks.com article only covers accessing the webcam. It does not cover the recording part.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)

That being said, this question has been asked several times before:

1. [How to record webcam and audio using webRTC and a server-based Peer connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571044/how-to-record-webcam-and-audio-using-webrtc-and-a-server-based-peer-connection)
2. [Access webcam without Flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644612/controlling-webcam-via-html5/9646193#9646193)
3. [HTML 5 streaming webcam video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976079/html-5-streaming-webcam-video/6976093#6976093)