# How to record a video in Angular with the use of ngx-webcam- capturing photos works

Tags: angular, video, webcam

I am currently working on a camera that would record videos in my angular app.  Currently, with the below code, I can access my camera and take snapshots.

Can someone please advise what I should amend in my code in order to have the ability to take a video?

App.module.ts file:

```
import {WebcamModule} from 'ngx-webcam';
...
imports: [
    ...
    WebcamModule
]
```

app.component.ts file:

```
import {WebcamImage} from 'ngx-webcam';
import {Subject, Observable} from 'rxjs';
...
export class AppComponent {
...
   // latest snapshot
   public webcamImage: WebcamImage = null;
   // webcam snapshot trigger
   private trigger: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
   triggerSnapshot(): void {
    this.trigger.next();
   }
   handleImage(webcamImage: WebcamImage): void {
    console.info('received webcam image', webcamImage);
    this.webcamImage = webcamImage;
   }
  
   public get triggerObservable(): Observable<void> {
    return this.trigger.asObservable();
   }
}
```

app.component.html file:

```
<webcam [height]="500" [width]="500" [trigger]="triggerObservable" (imageCapture)="handleImage($event)"></webcam>
<!-- Button Takes Photo -->
<button class="actionBtn" (click)="triggerSnapshot();">Take A Snapshot</button>
<!-- Snapshot Div where image will be shown -->
<div class="snapshot" *ngIf="webcamImage">
  <h2>Take your image or get another</h2>
  <img [src]="webcamImage.imageAsDataUrl"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ngx-webcam doesnt support out of the box recording, yet. https://github.com/basst314/ngx-webcam/issues/38
 
Its built in feature

- Webcam live view
- Photo capturing
- Smartphone compatibility for modern OS's (OS must support WebRTC/UserMedia API)
- Access to front- and back-camera, if multiple cameras exist
- Portrait & Landscape mode on smartphones
- Mirrored live-view for user-facing cameras - "selfie view" on phones
- Capturing of lossless pixel image data for better post-processing.
   
  I suggest looking into different packages or approaches.
- [how to record the video through webcam using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27738608/how-to-record-the-video-through-webcam-using-javascript)
   
  You may have to end up getting a little lower level and building your own solution.
- https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/recording-video

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the links, are you aware of any other webcams that do support it and can be used in angular?