# HTML5 video call, possible?

Tags: iphone, html, video, call

I am just curious the question above. I try to google it but most of the tutorial appear with video support related topic. So i guess stackoverflow could possible ans my curiosity.

:)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the status of the HTML 5 <video> tag and webcam integration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318834/whats-the-status-of-the-html-5-video-tag-and-webcam-integration)

Answer (score 2):

Been looking around for this a little myself, and it seems to be an interesting but still up-and-coming topic around the web.

The most concrete example I found was [here](http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2010/10/video-calls-using-html5-webkit-gtk-and.html) where they talk of a HTML5 Video Call experiment via WebKit-GTK.

Looking into it a bit further, the actual experiment details with some coding info can be found on Ericsson Labs page [here](https://labs.ericsson.com/developer-community/blog/beyond-html5-conversational-voice-and-video-implemented-webkit-gtk). Maybe that'll give you something to go on.

There's also talk of HTML5 video calling coming to Facebook and all, though those are just rumors. To answer your question, if these few examples are solid, I guess that Video Calling on HTML5 seems possible, though in its very early stages perhaps.

Comment: You're quite welcome :) If this helped you out, would appreciate a vote up and marking this off as answered. Thanks!

Comment: actually i am more interested to know if html5 can integrate video call in smartphone

Comment: Does apple allow webapps to access cameras? I don't believe so. (Plus they have a interest to not allow it because its competing with Facetime) even before you consider that angle, it might not be currently possible on the iOS platform.