# How do I broadcast video from my webcam with Html5?

Tags: html, html5-video, webcam, broadcast, webrtc

I am trying to build a simple web page that has access to my webcam and is able to broadcast the video taken from my webcam.

I am new to Html5 and I suppose that it is a complex task to build such a web page from scratch. I just want some experienced Html5 developers to provide me with some starting point, maybe some tutorials in this matter.

Comment: Does "New to HTML5" == "New to HTML"? Tutorials for specifically the HTML5 <video> tag? Also take note about streaming: Apple has a proprietary streaming protocol, almost a de facto default, but not w3c (yet): HLS

Comment: "not yet" part was enough for me. Thanks.

Comment: Bah, people who want to get around these, mix technologies. Flash streams, and if you want broad video you'll have Flash as a fallback in an <object> who is child of <video>. http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/blog/23499/the-future-of-mobile-video-is-apple-for-now also see http://diveinto.html5doctor.com/video.html <-- this is very good stuff despite the age.

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Native (not Flash) Webcam and Microphone access in Chrome, [demonstrated on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VP0SV3YWOWA&feature=player_detailpage#t=1426s) by Paul Kinlan (Google):

And check this out too: [Hands on: building an HTML5 photo booth with Chrome's new webcam API](http://arstechnica.com/business/news/2012/01/hands-on-building-an-html5-photo-booth-with-chromes-new-webcam-api.ars)

Comment: Good to know, though sentence at 24:14... may mean this won't help in the OP's case.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible in HTML5 yet.  You would need to use some sort of browser plugin like flash.

See this question: [What's the status of the HTML 5 <video> tag and webcam integration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318834/whats-the-status-of-the-html-5-video-tag-and-webcam-integration)

Comment: i'm sorry - it is possible, see below demonstration

Answer (score 0):

Broadcasting in **WebRTC** is **not yet possible** according to this [Google Developers Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8C8ouiXHHk).

**What you can do:**

1. Share your screen
2. Share static stuff (e.g. images, files, etc.) via DataChannels
3. Connect with group of people or individual and share your streams(audio + video)

Answer (score -2):

Make sure your webcam is behind software that can stream H264 over HTTP (look up at [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/) or so) and use the `<video>` tag and point it to your PC (open ports if you are behind NAT, common is 8080 but that is depending on your streaming software).

Point the source tag (NOT SRC in the video tag, some browsers hate that) to your external IP and port.